# Rselenium loops not able to extract data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to extract data tables from a website. There are 4 layers of drop downs- type, district, block and gram panchayat. I have created a loop which goes through the 5th option of layer - type,
then for district, it should select the block and then for block, it should select the gram panchayat and fetch the respective table.

I tried to build 4 loops and then finally extracted html_element to click the button. However, When I run the loop, it keep going through like this selecting option at index 1...to 75 (which is the number of districts) and then again it goes same instead of fetching the data table.
For now, I am trying to scrape just for one gram panchayat as trial but failing. Please help to resolve this:

```
  remoteDriver$navigate("https://sec.up.nic.in/ElecLive/resultsearch.aspx")
  Sys.sleep(2)

 remoteDriver$maxWindowSize()
 source <- remoteDriver$getPageSource()[[1]]
 list_position <- read_html(source) %>% 
 html_nodes("select#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPostTypes option") %>% html_text() %>% 
 .[-1]
 View(list_position)

 all_tables <- list()

 # Loop to select each type

 for (type_index in seq_along(list_position)) {
 type_position <- 5
 ddl_type <- remoteDriver$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                   value = "#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPostTypes")
 ddl_type$clickElement()
 Sys.sleep(1)

 cat("Selecting option at index:", type_index, "\n")

 type_option <- ddl_type$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                  value = sprintf("option:nth-child(%d)", type_position))
 type_option$clickElement()


 Sys.sleep(2)


 dist_positions <- read_html(source) %>% 
html_nodes("select#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict option") %>% 
html_text() %>% 
.[-1] 

for (dist_index in seq_along(dist_positions)) {
dist_position <- 1

ddl_district <- remoteDriver$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                         value = "#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict")
ddl_district$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(2)


cat("Selecting option at index:", dist_index, "\n")


selected_district <- ddl_district$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                  value = sprintf("option:nth-child(%d)", dist_position))

selected_district$clickElement() #clicking selected district


Sys.sleep(3)


block_positions <- read_html(source) %>% 
  html_nodes("select#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlBlock option") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  .[-1] 


for (block_index in seq_along(block_positions)){
  block_position <- 1
 
  ddl_block <- remoteDriver$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                        value = "#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlBlock")
  ddl_block$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(3)
  
  
  
  cat("Selecting option at index:", block_index, "\n")
  
  
  selected_block <- ddl_block$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                      value = sprintf("option:nth-child(%d)",  block_position))
  
  selected_block$clickElement()
  
 
  Sys.sleep(3)
  
  #extracting gp_list
  gp_positions <- read_html(source) %>% 
    html_nodes("select#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGpName option") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    .[-1] # Remove "All gp" option
  
  
  for (gp_index in c(1, 2)){
   
    ddl_gp <- remoteDriver$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                       value = "#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGpName")
    ddl_gp$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(3)
    
    cat("Selecting option at index:", gp_index, "\n")
    
   
    selected_gp <- ddl_gp$findElement(using = "css selector", 
                                      value = sprintf("option:nth-child(%d)", gp_index))
    
    selected_gp$clickElement() #clicking selected gp
    
   
    Sys.sleep(2)
    
  
    show_button <- remoteDriver$findElement(using = "css selector", 
    value =    "#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnshow")
    show_button$clickElement()
    
   
    Sys.sleep(4)
    
  
    candidate_table <- remoteDriver$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_table("#topstat > table:nth-child(8)")
    
    if (length(candidate_table) == 0){
      
      cat("No table available on the GP page\n")} else
      {
        
        current_table <- candidate_table[[1]] %>%
          as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique")
        
       
        print(current_table)
        
      
        all_tables[[length(all_tables) + 1]] <- current_table
        
        cat("Table successfully scraped from the GP page\n")
      }
  }}}
```

}

final_table <- bind_rows(all_tables)

Comment: Welcome to SO Abhishek Anand. You create an object gp_positions but then do nothing further with it in your most inner loop? You could start by determining how you want to use gp_positions in your inner loop. Also, it can be helpful (but not always) to test each loop separately to double-check if the data are being scraped correctly. Then you can work backwards from there. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for these insights. I will try to test the loops separately.